# Why is the text not aligning to the center of the bordered box?

Tags: html, css

[The misaligned image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j4R5.jpg)

```html
<menu style="list-style:none;text-align:center;font-size:200%;border: 6px solid white;border-style:dotted;margin-top:100px;margin-left:600px;margin-right:600px;padding-top:30px;color:GhostWhite;background: rgb(0,0,0,0.8)">
```

Idk why the text is not aligning in the center of the box even tho I gave text-align:center :(.(image attached )
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you need to show a working snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using a list inside the box - and browsers put a padding of 40px to the left of a ul element. So try applying padding::0  to your UL.

```css
.list-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #222;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.with-padding-removed {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>With padding removed</h2>

<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ul class="with-padding-removed">
    <li>Expensive breeds</li>
    <li>Cat memes</li>
    <li>Adopt</li>
    <li>Cat pictures</li>
    <li>Best breeds</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<h2>Without padding removed</h2>

<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ul class="without-padding-removed">
    <li>Expensive breeds</li>
    <li>Cat memes</li>
    <li>Adopt</li>
    <li>Cat pictures</li>
    <li>Best breeds</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

text-align css style does work well with block level tags such as h1. The following code makes the element centered But not excatly. I also changed the width of the element.

```html
<menu style="list-style:none;font-size:200%;border: 6px solid white;border-style:dotted;margin-top:100px;width:10%;margin-left:40%;margin-right:40%;padding-top:30px;color:GhostWhite;background: rgb(0,0,0,0.8)">
```